# rewrite the script without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please help rewrite the script without jquery.

here
http://jsfiddle.net/xMUdA/
I made a slide-out panel. used angularjs and jquery.

it is necessary that was used only angularjs

js:

```
var app = angular.module("moduleSlidePanel", []);

app.controller("controllerSlidePanel", function ($scope, $timeout){

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- implementation ---------- 
    $scope.visible = function(){        
        $('.slide_panel').addClass('showPanel');
    };

    $scope.invisible = function(){      
        $('.slide_panel').removeClass('showPanel');
    };

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- initialization ---------- 

});
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: Thank you. but if there is a way to use only angularjs? but not pure javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
<div class="slide_panel" ng-class="{'showPanel':show}">
    qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwerty<br />
    qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwerty<br />
    qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwerty<br />
    qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwerty<br />
    qwerty<br />
    qwerty<br />
    qwerty<br />
</div>

<div class="next" ng-click="show = true">show</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="next" ng-click="show = false">hide</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but not worked
http://jsfiddle.net/svDPz/

Comment: You are missing the `ng-class` on slide-panel div. Have a closer look at my answer.